# How to fix 403 Forbidden error in laravel application after hosting in a sub domain

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, http-status-code-404, cpanel, laravel-7

I get the 403 Forbidden error when I try to access my Laravel application from my subdomain.
[image]

My project is outside the public_html file in cPanel in a folder called app.
[image]

And i have created a symlink to the project public_html by running this code in cPanel terminal
[image]

```
ln -s ~/app/public_html/ ~/public_html
```

And I have set permission 644 to the project directory

Answer (score 0):

This might create an infinite loop and that is what creating the problem. However you may be able to create a symlink to any of the sub directories, it would work fine.

```
ln -s ~/app/public/uploads ~/public_html/uploads
```

Will work fine.